# "Assembly cannot be determined for an application store" exception with isolated storage

Tags: c#, isolatedstorage

I'm getting this exception (title) when trying to run the following code:

```
   public static String WriteSettings(String fileName, String settings)
    {
        try
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile settingsStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly | IsolatedStorageScope.User, null))
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, settingsStore)))
                {
                    writer.Write(settings);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return "Cannot save settings. The following error has occurred: " + e.Message;
        }

        return "Settings saved";
    }
```

The line on which the exception occurs is:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile settingsStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly | IsolatedStorageScope.User, null))
```

Any help greatly appreciated!!

Comment: any advances in solving the problem?

Comment: This was a good while ago now, I can't remember how it was resolved I'm afraid. Are you experiencing the same issue? Maybe there's something I can help with if you provide some context.

Comment: Have a look at the exceptions table here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/za7b745z.aspx

Comment: Frankly speaking it's not very clear what is meant by "evidence" I call GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.Roaming | IsolatedStorageScope.User, null) and get the same exception.

Comment: Found good article about ISF: http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84438/isolated-storage/